# join polygons without overlay (and plot)

Tags: python, shapely

I'm trying to join a set of polygons to create a single polygon. These polygons (they are not closed as in the last point being equal to the first), their edges are exactly equal at some point:

```
poly1 = [(0,0), (1,0), (1,0.25), (1, 0.5), (1,0.75), (1,1), (0,1)]
poly2 = [(2,0), (2,0.25), (1,0.25), (1,0.5), (1,0.75), (2,1)]
```

It is visible that the polygons "connect" at: (1,0.25), (1, 0.5), (1,0.75)

How do I join these polygons to a single polygon?

My current code:

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon,MultiPolygon
import os
import glob
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch

basePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # defines the directory where the current file resides

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(basePath, '*.txt'))

polygons = []

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') # file containing a list of x and y points

    points = []
    for index, point in data.iterrows():
        points.append((point['x'], point['y']))
    polygons.append(Polygon(points))

u = cascaded_union(polygons)
fig2 = plt.figure(2, figsize=(10,10), dpi=90)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
patch2b = PolygonPatch(u, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE, alpha=1, zorder=2)
ax2.add_patch(patch2b)
```

When I run the above code it doesn't work. When I try to get the x, y coords from u I cannot (u is a multipolygon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your second Polygon has a self-join.

```
poly1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,0.25), (1, 0.5), (1,0.75), (1,1), (0,1)])
poly2 = Polygon([(2,0), (2,0.25), (1,0.25), (1,0.5), (1,0.75), (2,1)])
poly2_corrected = Polygon([(2,0), (1,0.25), (1,0.5), (1,0.75), (2,1)])
```

Then, we have:

```
poly1
```

[image]

```
poly2
```

[image]

```
poly2_corrected
```

[image]

We get an error when we try:

```
u = cascaded_union([poly1, poly2])
```

But not for:

```
u_corrected = cascaded_union([poly1, poly2_corrected])
u_corrected
```

[image]

```
print u
```

POLYGON ((1 0.25, 1 0, 0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0.75, 2 1, 2 0, 1 0.25))